# Can this be done in one query?

Tags: sql, mysql

table

```
id (primary)
key1,key2,key3 (secondary)
```

given id N

query #1

```
select key1,key2,key3 from table where id=N  --  key1n,key2n,key3n
```

query #2

```
select * from table where key1 = key1n and key2 = key2n  --  results...
```

Comment: Not clear on what you're after… please clarify

Comment: Your question is pretty unclear.  Perhaps you could explain why `SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE id=N` is not sufficient.

Comment: @dnagirl: I believe the @op wants all records that share the values of `key1, key2, key3` with the record `N`.

Comment: Let's say we have `{id=1,key1=a,key2=b,key3=c} {id=2,key1=a,key2=b,key3=d} {id=3,key1=b,key2=c,key3=d} {id=4,key1=a,key2=b,key3=e}`. Is the expected result the records with id=1,2, and 4?

Comment: i'm looking for all the rows that have key1 and key2.  key1 and key2 are obtained from the one record with an id of N.

Comment: for martinho yes those would be the results if my n was 1 or 2 or 4... so yes to your question.  oddly i'm getting a syntax error on quassnoi's answer...mysql 5.1 ...not sure what's going on says unknown column t1.key2 in on clause...

Comment: ok it worked!!! million thanks to Quassnoi!!!

Comment: @Steven: if Quassnoi's answer solved your problem, you should click the check box outline below the answer score to mark it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 6):

```
SELECT  t2.*
FROM    table t1
JOIN    table t2
ON      t2.key1 = t1.key1
        AND t2.key2 = t1.key2
        AND t2.key3 = t1.key3
WHERE   t1.id = '$N'
```

Comment: Since id is the primary key, won't the result of this just be the same as `select * from table where id=N`?  I'm probably missing something obvious.  I suppose one difference would be if any of the keyn values were null.

Comment: @Mark: my query return all records sharing the values of `key1, key2, key3` with the record `N`, while your query will only return the record `N`.

Comment: Conceptually what you are saying makes sense, but I am not able to see a difference.  Maybe my brain got turned off over the weekend and hasn't started up yet.  I'll just have to set up some data and play with it when I get a chance.  Thanks.

Comment: @Mark: the table: `(id, key1, key2, key3)`. Three records: `(1, 1, 1, 1)`, `(2, 1, 1, 1)`, `(3, 2, 2, 2)`. The @op wants "all records with the same keys as record `1` has", that is records `1` and `2`.